# Pairing up elements in different collections: how to avoid deep nestled for loops?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory, nested-loops, graph-algorithm

I just caught myself writing the most horrible piece of code I have seen, while attempting to solve a graph-topography problem I encountered. Before I go into the details, let me just make the question very clear: **I have an unholy number of nestled loops/conditionals**, and I am wondering if there's a way I can avoid it.

I have the following objects at my disposal:

1. A `Dataset` which is a collection of data points from a specific experiment. These data points contain `Element`s that have (1 -> many) relations to `Set`s. (approx. size 2-5K elements)
2. A `Database` which is a reference of all `Element`s and `Set`s, regardless if they are observed in the experiment or not. Also this object has methods for data retrieval.. (approx. 30K elements, 10K sets)
3. A collection of `Set`s that are evaluated based on the dataset (#1).

What I want to do is to build a graph that has `Element`s as nodes, and `Set` membership relations as edges.

**Example:**
Take two elements, *e1* and *e2*. Assume that *e1* is a member of sets: *S1*, *S2* and *S4*; while *e2* is a member of *S1*, *S3* and *S4*. In this case, there should be two edges between *e1* and *e2*, that represent sets *S1* and *S4*.

Note that `Dataset` object will typically contain a small portion of `Element`s that exist in the `Database`, so in the example above there a large number of other elements that should not be in the graph (because they are not featured in the `Dataset`) even though they have membership to the sets in question.

Given the problem, my "simple" (read: *naive*) solution (in pseudocode) was to loop over:

1. the dataset --> `for (data d : dataset)`
2. the sets `d` is a member of --> `for(set s : database.getSetsWith(d))`
3. the elements of `s` --> `for (elem e : s.getElements())`
4. the remaining elements in dataset --> `for(data dx : dataset - d)`

AND create `(d, dx)` pair if the two elements are a part of the set `s` together.

This solution is composed of 4 nested `for` loops and a conditional check deep down to eventual pairing. It's UGLY, SLOW, and prone to cause problems. But I'm not sure if there's anything else I can do.

Suggestions?

---

Ref:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213910/maximum-nesting-for-loops-and-conditionals
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199196/why-are-nested-loops-considered-bad-practice

Comment: can you post your four loops and the check

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of this process (both code-wise and complexity-theory-wise) is a function of the input and output data structures.  It would probably help from a code clarity perspective if your `Dataset` and `Set` classes (correctly) implemented `java.util.Set`, and it would open a few doors if your `Element` class provided an `equals(Object)` that satisfies the expectations of the Collections API, with a corresponding `hashCode()` method.  (If reference equality is suitable for your `Element`s then you don't need anything more there.)

Having those things in place, this is a bit less complex, and it might look and feel a little cleaner, too:

1. Create a `java.util.HashSet` containing all the elements of your `Dataset` (call it `dataElements`).
2. Remove any element `e` from `dataElements`.
3. For each set `s` to which `e` belongs,

   1. Create a `java.util.HashSet` copy, `s1`, of `s`
   2. Form in `s1` the intersection of `s1` and `dataElements`
   3. For each remaining element `e1` in `s1`, create an (undirected) edge between `e` and `e1`.
4. If `dataElements` is non-empty, go back to step (2)

In code, perhaps that would look like so:

```
HashSet<Element> dataElements = new HashSet<>(dataset);
Iterator<Element> dataIterator = dataElements.iterator();

while (dataIterator.hasNext()) {
    Element e = dataIterator.next();

    dataIterator.remove();
    for (com.my.Set<Element> s : database.getSetsWith(e)) {
        HashSet<Element> s1 = new HashSet<>(s);

        s1.retainAll(dataElements);
        for (Element e1 : s1) {
            // create edge (e, e1, s) ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can do similar even if your classes do not implement `java.util.Set` -- that part is mainly for convenience in making copies (via the `HashSet` constructor).  Your `Element` class does need to provide suitable `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, though, if those provided by `Object` won't do.

Notes:

- The approach I present naturally avoids producing unwanted duplicate edges (given that edges arising from co-membership in different sets are wanted as separate edges).
- Checking membership in a hash is quite fast (O(0), given a reasonably good hashing function), and you need to do a lot of membership checking.  Few other kinds of collection data structures perform membership checking as efficiently.
- That approach achieves one fewer level of nested loop, at the expense of making copies of some of your data structures.  (Copies are made so that the algorithm can freely destroy them.)
- That approach involves *no* conditionals.

**Correction**: that approach involves exactly one explicit conditional, at step (4) of the algorithm.  That corresponds to the `while()` condition of the outermost loop.  Also, the enhanced `for` loops have implicit conditionals of the same kind.  I'm supposing that loop termination conditions were not the conditionals that bothered you.

Comment: If that's still too slow then you could tweak it a little further by caching the set copies `s1`.  That could both avoid many of the set copy operations and speed the set intersection operations.  The resulting code would be a little more complex, and the memory requirement a little higher.

Comment: Thnx for the answer.. Im giving it a try, will get back to this after some testing of the code..